# c# Business Object list all reports using a Universe

Tags: c#, sdk, business-objects

Using Business Object C# SDK to query BO Database.  I'm trying to list
 all reports using a Universe. I can compute SI_ID, SI_NAME but not SI_WEBI property that contains report ID for my next query.

```
string boQuery = "SELECT si_id,si_name,si_webi,si_cuid FROM CI_AppObjects WHERE SI_NAME = '#UniverseName' AND SI_KIND = 'Universe'";
InfoStore boInfoStore = new InfoStore(boEnterpriseService);
InfoObjects boInfoObjects = boInfoStore.Query(boQuery);
```

Is possible to get si_webi IDs property and afterward get all the report with every ID computed:

```
SELECT SI_ID,SI_NAME,SI_KIND FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS WHERE SI_KIND IN ('WEBI', 'FULLCLIENT' ) AND SI_ID = #si_webi_ID
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to iterate through all results of the first query to get the contents of the `SI_WEBI` property, or combine both steps into one with a relationship query:

```
select si_name 
  from ci_infoobjects 
 where parents("si_name='webi-universe'","si_name='<<universe name>>'")
```